# I am trying to get one element of a website but it prints "none" (Python Requests)

Tags: python, python-requests, request

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.gamerdvr.com/gamer/cookz/videos"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
element = soup.find('span', id_="most-recorded")

print(element)
```

This always prints "none" but when I go to the website, I can see it. I even deleted all cookies and it's still there.

Comment: What if you try : element = soup.find("span",{"id":"most-recorded"})
And did you try to just print the full response and see if your element is visible ?

Comment: try `time.sleep(5)` and wait for a page to load first and check in `soup` you can see the content.

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying a user agent, the site does not give you the tag you need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = "https://www.gamerdvr.com/gamer/cookz/videos"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
element = soup.find('span', {'id': "most-recorded"}).get_text(strip=True)

print(element)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Fortnite
```